# HtmlUnit stucks on js compile

Tags: javascript, java, htmlunit

I run this code

```
val client = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME)
val url = "https://belovo.drom.ru/jaguar/f-pace/26324638.html"
val req = new WebRequest(new URL(url))
client.getPage[HtmlPage](req)
```

Used version of HtmlUnit

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
   <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
   <version>2.28</version>
</dependency>
```

Loading of page stucks on compilation https://c.rdrom.ru/js/DromContacts.min.js?3176009243

This js code is very obfuscated, maybe for this reason it happens.

This lines in log

```
[2017-12-25 17:15:21,657] WARN  [main] Obsolete content type encountered: 'application/x-javascript'.
[2017-12-25 17:15:21,658] TRACE [main] Javascript compile https://c.rdrom.ru/js/DromContacts.min.js?3176009243
```

and then nothing happens for long time (5 min).

Have someone faced with such problem?

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? I don't think those log messages are very worrying. Obfuscation shouldn't be a problem, although it makes debugging tricky so if it does turn out to be a javascript problem then you should try to replace it with a non-obfuscated version if you can.

Comment: I expect that WebClient successfully load the page without blocking on js compilation for infinite time.

Comment: How do you know that javascript compilation is the problem?

Comment: If it was going to fail parsing javascript then I think it would just fail immediately. Are there any other suspicious-looking lines in the log? Or are there any parts where it says it's attempting to do something but never says it's finished doing it?

Comment: Cause I try to set timeout to js execution
      client.setJavaScriptTimeout(5000)

and it fails with TimeoutError on this js file

Comment: That doesn't mean it's a compilation problem. It looks like the script is trying to do something that takes more than 5 seconds. Do you know what that script is supposed to do? Do you know it's that script, or could it be some other one? Just because the log lines about that script are at the end of the log doesn't mean that script is the problem - there are probably lots of different things happening in parallel. What else does the log say? My guess is it says somewhere that it is trying to connect to a server and then doesn't error but also doesn't say it's connected successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this in the past for some pages. Because HtmlUnit does not render the content some width/height methods are returning more or less fixed values. And some clever javascript tires to layout text using a loop that cuts the text and then checks the width again. In my case this leads to an endless loop.

If there is some time during the next days i will try your example.

Comment: Sorry but i had no good news, have done a first look with the debugger/profiler and it looks like the obfuscated source is a problem. Please try to report this to the Rhino folks, because HtmlUnit is based on Rhino and this looks like a problem with Rhino to me.